# In Ruby, how can I initialize instance variables in new objects of core classes created from literals

Tags: ruby, oop

```
class Object
  attr_reader :foo
  def initialize
    @foo = 'bar'
  end
end

Object.new.foo # => 'bar'
''.foo # => nil
//.foo # => nil
[].foo # => nil
```

I want them all to return `'bar'`

Am aware that you can do this already:

```
class Object
  def foo
    'bar'
  end
end
```

But I specifically want to initialize a state variable. Also note that this doesn't work.

```
class String
  alias_method :old_init, :initialize
  def initialize(*args)
    super
    old_init(*args)
  end
end

class Object
  attr_reader :foo
  def initialize
    @foo = 'bar'
    super
  end
end

''.foo # => nil
```

Nor does this:

```
class String
  attr_reader :foo
  def initialize
    @foo = 'bar'
  end
end

''.instance_variables # => []
```

I'm beginning to think that this isn't actually possible.

Comment: The reason this isn't working for you is that all those other classes that inherit from object override `initialize`, and don't bother to invoke the superclass's version of it.

Answer (score 5):

This **is** possible.

```
class Object
  class << self
    Kernel.send :define_method, :foo do #Object.send to be more restrictive
      @foo = 'bar'
    end
  end
end
```

.

```
irb(main):023:0> class Object
irb(main):024:1> class << self
irb(main):025:2> Kernel.send :define_method, :foo do 
irb(main):026:3* @foo = 'bar'
irb(main):027:3> end
irb(main):028:2> end
irb(main):029:1> end
=> #<Proc:0x00007f5ac89db168@(irb):25>
irb(main):030:0> x = Object.new
=> #<Object:0x7f5ac89d6348>
irb(main):031:0> x.foo
=> "bar"
irb(main):032:0> [].foo
=> "bar"
irb(main):033:0> //.foo
=> "bar"
```

It's important to understand eigenclasses.  Every class is implemented mysteriously by the Ruby interpreter as a hidden class type:

```
irb(main):001:0> class Object
irb(main):002:1>   def eigenclass
irb(main):003:2>     class << self; self; end
irb(main):004:2>   end
irb(main):005:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> x = Object.new
=> #<Object:0x7fb6f285cd10>
irb(main):007:0> x.eigenclass
=> #<Class:#<Object:0x7fb6f285cd10>>
irb(main):008:0> Object.eigenclass
=> #<Class:Object>
irb(main):009:0> Object.class
=> Class
```

So, in your example, when you're trying to call foo on your objects, it's operating on the class `#<Object:0x7fb6f285cd10>`.  However, what you want it to operate on is the secret class `#<Class:#<Object:0x7fb6f285cd10>>`

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

If the thing you're trying to return (here, `'bar'`) requires much more setup cost than a small String, you could use the memoized version of [HermanD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914814/in-ruby-how-can-i-initialize-instance-variables-in-new-objects-of-core-classes-c/914838#914838):

```
class Object
  def foo
    @foo ||= begin
      'bar' # something far more complicated than just "'bar'"
    end
  end
end
```

You could even use the memoization for cheap stuff like Strings if you *really* need the instance variable to be set (for some reason that I can't quite think of at them moment):

```
class Object
  def foo
    @foo ||= 'bar'
  end
end
```

Comment: +1, but this wont work if you invoke instance_variable_get before using the accessor, it's interesting that you can't rely on Object's #initialize.

Comment: boy, that's a pretty awkward case, but I have _no_ _doubt_ that some obscure library will call into this and it will blow up and you'll go, "WTF?"

Answer (score 0):

It's not an instance variable, but will meet the requirements of your example

```
class Object
  def foo
    'bar'
  end
end
```